# Java8: How can I use Pair in Hashmap

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8

I am completely new to Java:
I am trying to create a HashMap in Java 8: where keys are objects of a class State and values I would like to be tuples of (string,state).
I searched the web for tuples in Java and I found this class called Pair that looked like a binary tuple ( I read here [:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/Pair.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/Pair.html)  and here : https://www.techiedelight.com/five-alternatives-pair-class-java/ ) - But I am confused because I also read a post here in stackoverflow saying that there are no pairs in Java8.
I wrote this line:

```java
 HashMap<State, Pair<String, State>> visited = new HashMap<>();
```

I imported :

```java
import java.util.*;
javafx.util.Pair
```

I get error messages like:

```
   javafx could not be resolved  
   Pair cannot be resolved to a type
```

How can I do what I described in Java 8?

Comment: Use [Apache common's Pair](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.9/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html)

Comment: The Pair class you found is a part of JavaFX, which has to be loaded separately from base Java.  Alternatively, you can write your own Pair class.  It's just a key, value pair.

Comment: Writing a generic Pair class is a simple exercise if you're learning Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
record Pair ( String string , State state ) {}
```

## Records

The [Answer by Bykov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68335803/642706) is good if you want a general mutable pair class. Alternatively, you can whip up a specific [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) pairing quite easily in Java 16+ by using the [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) feature.

A record is a brief way to write a class whose main purpose is to communicate data transparently and immutably. You simply declare the type and name of each member field. The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

Here is our entire class definition in six words:

```
record Pair ( String string , State state ) {}
```

You would of course use more descriptive class and field names.

Instantiate like a conventional class.

```
Pair p = new Pair( "whatever" , tennessee ) ;
```

You can declare a record locally, as well as nested or separately.

That `record` above is equivalent to the conventional code seen below. Modern [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)s such [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) can convert a record to a conventional class, creating this source code.

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.util.Objects;

public final class Pair {
    private final String string;
    private final State state;

    public Pair ( String string , State state ) {
        this.string = string;
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String string () { return string; }

    public State state () { return state; }

    @Override
    public boolean equals ( Object obj ) {
        if ( obj == this ) return true;
        if ( obj == null || obj.getClass () != this.getClass () ) return false;
        var that = ( Pair ) obj;
        return Objects.equals ( this.string , that.string ) &&
                Objects.equals ( this.state , that.state );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode () {
        return Objects.hash ( string , state );
    }

    @Override
    public String toString () {
        return "Pair[" +
                "string=" + string + ", " +
                "state=" + state + ']';
    }

}
```

Comment: I wonder why Map.Entry does not have a `setKey()`method, it's a Pair itself.

Comment: @LMC Because it makes no sense to change the key on a map entry, by definition. Changing the key on-the-fly would ruin its participation in the map. That class is *not* a general pairing, it is an entry in a map. If you want a mutable pairing, use the class defined in the [Answer by Bykov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68335803/642706). For an immutable pairing, define a `record` as shown in my Answer here.

Comment: thank you for the insight, but I am forced to use Java 8 for a particular system

Comment: @brucebanner I added the equivalent conventional code. This code works in Java 8.

Comment: thank you for the help . One question : this pair class where should be defined? Is it visible since it is public from all of my files in a prticular project in eclipse?

Answer (score 4):

I'll give you advice, try to create your own Pair class implementation, it's enough easy:

```
public class Pair<K, V> {

    private final K first;

    private final V second;

    public Pair(final K first, final V second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public static <K, V> Pair<K, V> of(K first, V second) {
        return new Pair<>(first, second);
    }

    public K getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public V getSecond() {
        return second;
    }
}
```

In your implementation, you can declare any constructors, static initialize methods, or deserialize's rules. It'll more comfortable than JavaFX Pair.

Comment: this class where should be defined, in order to be accessed by my main?, if I define it inside my main it does not recognize my methods

Answer (score 0):

1. For using tuples, there's a great lib [JOOL](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jooq/jool).
2. If you want to use a custom object as hash map keys, do not forger to correctly define `equals()` and `hashCode()` for this class.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: After some suggestions here I tried to implement pair with hashmap, can you spot anything wrong with this code ?
I included this code inside a class "my_struct"

```java
 public class tuple<Character, my_struct> extends HashMap<Character, my_struct> {

      public tuple() {
        super();
      }

      public Character getMove(HashMap<Character, my_struct> c) {
              Set<Character> w = c.keySet();
              Character move;
              for(Character i : w) {
                  move = i;
              }
              return move;
     }

      public my_struct getPrev(HashMap<Character, my_struct> c) {
          Collection<my_struct> w = c.values();
          my_struct prev;
          for(my_struct i : w) {
              prev = i;
          }
          return prev;
      }
      
  }
```

Then I am trying to use both get() method from HashMap class  and
my new methods but it won't work:

HashMap<Character, my_struct> i = new tuple();